# had been and the day before

Tags: past-tense, perfect-constructions

Are the following sentences grammatically correct?

1. He asked me if I was depressed the day before.
2. He asked me if I had been depressed the day before.

Please explain. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct.  Some speakers will "backshift" the tense in the reported speech, while others will not.  There is no requirement to do so.

Answer (score 0):

"yesterday" must be the preterite, when it comes to "the day before", preterite and past perfect tenses are right.
 The phrase of "had been" stress the procedure.